# Trouble with adding a wp_enqueue_script on wordpress

Tags: functions, jquery

I have this JQuery script in my functions.php

```
function hideout_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'hideout-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
wp_style_add_data( 'hideout-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hideout-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main-nav.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hideout_scripts' );
```

It loads with this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: openNav is not defined
at HTMLElement.onclick ((index):288)
```

here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nav = $("#menu > ul > li");
    nav.find("li").hide();
nav.click(function () {
    nav.not(this).find("li").hide();
    $(this).find("li").slideToggle();
});

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = "flex";
    $("#menu ul").slideToggle();
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
    $("#menu ul").slideToggle();
}

$(function () {
    nav.mouseleave(function () {
$(this).find("li").slideUp();
    });
});

$(window).on("resize load", function () {
    var win = $(this);
if (win.width() <= 973) {
    $("#close").attr("style", "display:none;");
    $("#open").attr("style", "display:flex;");
    $("#menu ul").attr("style", "display:none;");
} else {
    $("#close").attr("style", "display:flex;");
    $("#menu ul").attr("style", "display:flex;");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<i id="open" onclick="openNav()" class="icon-bars-solid"></i> <i id="close" onclick="closeNav()" class="icon-times-solid"></i>
```

My code works on code pen but if I use it on my site it conflicts with other scripts on WP. I'm lost, I just don't get why it does not work

Comment: Where is `openNav` called? I can see it's defined in your file, but it's never used anywhere. I also see the entire code block inside the dom ready call has broken indentation

Comment: Also when and how are you calling `wp_enqueue_script`? Are you calling it on the right hook or is it just in the top level of the file?

Comment: I updated my post and the script was made by someone else I just don't understand why it works on my codepen but not on my site

Comment: Thanks for the update, I still don't see where `openNav` was called, is there a missing part of this question? `openNav` is defined but it is never used so the error you are encountering should not be possible. It references an `onclick` event handler, but there is no `onclick` in any of the code blocks in your question

Comment: I forgot the HTML `<i id="open" onclick="openNav()" class="icon-bars-solid"></i> <i id="close" onclick="closeNav()" class="icon-times-solid"></i>`

Comment: I think your top block is missing a closing brace so you're defining the function inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` document ready handler scope not the global scope. So it's not available for the onclick handler. Or maybe the scope was deliberate, you use nav lower down? So you could just move openNav out of that to the very top of the script, since it doesn't depend on nav.